# Java how to make JTextArea Accesible from different class and write in integer

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextarea

I would like to know how can I make my `JTextArea` global and how can I use that to write in it with the result I get as an integer?

I am trying to do program for queues with linked link implementation but I don't actually use the `LinkedList` class. I have two different classes in my project. There is one class which is `deneme2`. In that class I have the queue methods. In the second class I have the `JFrame`, so I would like to get my enqueue and dequeue result in `JTextArea`. So far I could only use `println` but can't manage to get it into the `JTextArea`.

This is my `deneme4` class

```
   public class Deneme4 extends JFrame {
public static void main(String a[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    SecondFrame frame = new SecondFrame();

}}
```

This is the `Queue` class for the GUI I tried to make

```
public class Queue {

public static interface MessageOutput {

    void appendMessage(String message);

    void appendHead(String message);
}

private MessageOutput msgOutput = new MessageOutput() {
    @Override
    public void appendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void appendHead(String head) {
        System.out.println(head);
    }
};

public void setMessageOutput(MessageOutput value) {
    msgOutput = value;
}

public void setHeadOutput(MessageOutput value) {
    msgOutput = value;
}

private Node front, rear;
private int currentSize;

private class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;
}

public Queue() {
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    currentSize = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (currentSize == 0) {
        msgOutput.appendMessage("Que is Empty\n");
    }
    return currentSize == 0;
}

public int dequeue() {
    int data = front.data;
    front = front.next;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        rear = null;
    }
    currentSize--;
    msgOutput.appendMessage(data + " removed from the queue\n");

    return data;
}

public int enqueue(int data) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Node oldRear = rear;
    rear = new Node();
    rear.data = data;
    rear.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        front = rear;
    } else {
        oldRear.next = rear;
    }
    currentSize++;
    msgOutput.appendMessage(data + " added to the queue\n");
    return data;
}

public int queueSize() {
    msgOutput.appendMessage("Size of the Que is" + currentSize + "\n");
    return currentSize;
}

public int getHead() {
    int data = front.data;
    msgOutput.appendHead("Head of the Que is " + data + "\n");
    return data;
}}
```

and this is my QueueFrame which i want when the button clicked it outputs the value to txt1 but cant seem to do it

```
public class QueueFrame extends JFrame implements Queue.MessageOutput {

private JTextArea txt1;
private JTextArea txt2;
private JTextArea txt3;
private JButton b1;
private JButton b2;
private Queue queue = new Queue();

public static interface MessageOutput {

    void appendMessage(String message);

    void appendHead(String message);
}

private MessageOutput msgOutput = new MessageOutput() {
    @Override
    public void appendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void appendHead(String head) {
        System.out.println(head);
    }
};

public void setMessageOutput(MessageOutput value) {
    msgOutput = value;
}

public void setHeadOutput(MessageOutput value) {
    msgOutput = value;
}

@Override
public void appendHead(String head) {
    txt2.append(head);
}

public QueueFrame() throws FileNotFoundException {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    b1 = new JButton("Load up the Que");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    queue.setMessageOutput((Queue.MessageOutput) queue.
                    queue.enqueue(s.nextInt());
                }
                s.close();
                queue.queueSize();
                queue.getHead();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(QueueFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
    b2 = new JButton("Head of the Que");
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            queue.getHead();
        }
    });

    txt1 = new JTextArea();
    txt2 = new JTextArea();
    txt3 = new JTextArea();

    txt1.setEditable(false);
    txt2.setEditable(false);
    txt3.setEditable(true);

    b1.setBounds(50, 100, 180, 100);
    b2.setBounds(50, 300, 180, 100);
    txt1.setBounds(600, 100, 200, 600);
    txt2.setBounds(300, 300, 180, 100);
    txt3.setBounds(300, 100, 180, 100);
    frame.add(b1);
    frame.add(b2);
    frame.add(txt1);
    frame.add(txt2);
    frame.add(txt3);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(1000, 1500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

}}
```

Comment: "*ho can i make my JTextArea global"* - you should, as much as possible, avoid using global variables of any time. You should always be careful exposing UI elements, as it allows others to modify them in unexpected ways (like removing them from their container).  Instead, focus on the use of "observer patterns", which allow you to register interest to classes which can the generate notifications when some state changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to this problem. This is the way that I would approach it:

Create an interface called MessageOutput inside the class deneme2 like this:

```
public class deneme2 {
    public static interface MessageOutput {
        void appendMessage(String message);
    } 
}
```

And in the same class, you need a reference to the MessageOutput so you can append message to it. And let's initialize it to some default implementation in case no one set it later:

```
private MessageOutput msgOutput = new MessageOutput() {
    @override
    public void appendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
};
```

And so you need a setter to the msgOutput field:

```
public void setMessageOutput(MessageOutput value) {
    msgOutput = value;
}
```

And so you can now change all the println code to use MessageOutput's appendMessage() method:

```
public int dequeue() {
    . . . 

    msgOutput.appendMessage(data + " removed from the queue");
    return data;
}
```

Then let MainFrame implements deneme2.MessageOutput. Note that you can no longer use the JTextArea as a local variable, you must make it an attribute of MainFrame:

```
public class MainFrame implements deneme2.MessageOutput {
    @override
    public void appendMessage(String message) {
        txt2.append(message);
    }
}
```

And finally, update the main() method to pass the MainFrame to the deneme2 instance:

```
MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
queue.setMessageOutput(frame);
```

And you should start processing the queue after the MainFrame is created.

Comment: and also how can i make jtextarea as the attribute of MainFrame?

Comment: i have done all, the only problem i am having is when i queue.setMessageOutput(frame); this in the main method it gives error with the queue

Comment: I have actually sorted it out, was doing the JTextArea wasnt able to make it as attribute but finally made it

Comment: I have played it up a bit and trying to output the message in the MainFrame, how can i do that so i want the queue.setMessageOutput(frame); in my MainFrame how can i do that i keep getting error. JFrame cannot be converted into message output how can i fix that?

Comment: You need to make sure the "frame" variable you passed to setMessageOutput() is of type MainFrame not just JFrame, and need to ensure MainFrame has implemented the deneme2.MessageOutput interface.

Comment: I have update the code could you be able to check QueueFrame and when i press the button it gives error because of that output. if i delete it, it prints in console. Have to finish this by 12 got assaigment aha

Comment: Try to change:                    queue.setMessageOutput((Queue.MessageOutput) queue) to
queue.setMessageOutput(QueueFrame.this);

Comment: still get the same error have you got skype or something we can speak on ?

Comment: i think its because somehow i need to do it in the enqueue it self but i cant do that either, cant we just call the txt1 to there?

Comment: its weird it works on queue.head but doesnt work on that one

Comment: How about:

                 queue.setMessageOutput(new Queue.MessageOutput() {
                     @Override
     public void appendMessage(String message) {
      txt1.append(message);
     }
                 });

Comment: i cant manage to write it in can you update your code above so i can do it from there if thats okay

Comment: got it now i forgot to add this 
public void appendMessage(String message) {
        txt1.append(message);
    } on my queueframe